# Access, lookup for data in another table if matches

Tags: ms-access, lookup

I have a Union query with invoice data like invoice number, supplier and so on. This query is created for the purpose of providing credit note information.

My problem arise when I would like to provide exchange rate for invoices in different currencies. If there is for example RON currency, I need to check currency and date of invoice and then provide value from another table.

I stored currencies and their values in another database. I wanted to use Dlookup function but it works only current database. Not sure what can I do. Is VBA needed here or it can be avoided?

Edit:
Having problem with syntax:

Query:

```
SELECT [Faktury].InvoiceNumber, [Faktury].InvoiceDate, [Faktury].InvoiceCountry, [Faktury].Currency, DLookUp("Value","Tabela1","Currency1 =" & [Currency]) AS Wyr1
FROM [Faktury];
```

Dlookup syntax:

```
DLookUp("Value";"Tabela1";"Currency1 =" & [Currency])
```

Query has column with `Currency` used in invoice and `Tabela1` has `Currency1` and `Value`. I get error or no value is shown...

Comment: Where are you running this `DLookUp`, in VBA? And what is the query you are referring to that contains the column *currency*?

Comment: Dlookup is run as a query Column. Please look at edit.

Comment: Don't use `DLookUp` here, just use use 'Tabela1' as a normal table in the query.

Comment: Right... LEFT JOIN. I was not thinking clearly at that moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To access a a table in another database you can create a [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-data-in-another-Access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6) to it:

Go to *External Data* > *Access* (although you could use any other type of data source) > choose the database file, and select *Link to the data source by creating a linked table.*

[image: Link database]

Then click *Ok* and select the table(s) you want to link (i.e. use in your database). Now you can use the table (*Currency* in my example) in your queries or in VBA like a normal table. For example with `DLookup` in VBA:

```
MsgBox DLookup("EuroValue", "Currency", "ID='" & InputBox("Currency?") & "'")
```

or in a (SQL) query:

```
SELECT EuroValue FROM [Currency] WHERE ID='USD';
```

or

```
SELECT DLookUp("EuroValue","Currency","ID='USD'");
```